# Настройка VPN подключения на маршрутизаторе Mikrotik

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, vpn, mikrotik, маршрутизатор

Есть домашний компьютер(LAN), маршрутизатор Mikrotik, и выход в интернет. Также есть учетная запись для доступа к VPN (L2TP IPsec).
Мне нужно настроить VPN на маршрутизаторе таким образом, чтобы все данные которые я отправляю/получаю в интернете, шли через VPN.
VPN подключение вроде настроил (какой-то трафик идет):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема остается в том, что я не знаю как перенаправить трафик со своего компьютера(и других LAN портов) на это VPN соединение. Может кто сможет подсказать как это сделать?

Сразу скажу: с сетями опыта почти нет, с Mikrotik работаю первый раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое: бросайте затею пользоваться через браузер и кройте 80 порт, оставляйте включенным только winbox и укажите с каких ip адресов можно будет заходить.

ip-->Routs указать маршрут выхода в инет через ваш созданный VPN!